# openstack: how to access the horizon dashboard?

Tags: openstack

I just followed the devstack install page: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

and followed the exact instructions with a fresh 18.04LTS ubuntu image from Linode.

after running the last step: ./stack.sh

the docs says "You can access horizon to experience the web interface to OpenStack, and manage vms, networks, volumes, and images from there"

Great, but it doesn't say how. Googling it, I found several suggestions, but none work, e..g

```
http://myip/ - gives apache default page.
http://myip/dashboard  -- page not found
http://myip/horizon -- page not found.
http://myip:3000 -- site cant be reached.
https://myip/
etc.
```

Is there any way to see if horizon is running?
How do I access it?

As a bonus question, which virtualization SW is it using?  KVM?